# clion ubuntu navigate back

Tags: clion

I use Clion. How can I navigate back if I follow links by pressing ctrl+mouse click? If I press ctrl+mouse click on a function, I come to the declaration. But how to I navigate back? On Windows I think it was ctrl+l.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `CLion` v2016.1.1, when you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+`mouse-click` on a function it will open a new tab in which you can find the function declaration (*this works if function usage and declaration/definition are in differents file*).

To come back you only have to close the tab.

Instead, if you want to come back to a previous view in the same file you can select from menu `Navigate` > `Back`.
There is also a shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (*left*), but there is problem with it: it won't work because it is  caught by Unity when you want to change a workspace. If you want to use a shortcut you can change the keybinding in `CLion` preferences. To do so follow these steps:

1. Open keymap preference: from menu select `Edit` > `Settings...` > `Keymap`
2. Look for `back` in the search bar.
3. Watch at results and on `Navigate` entry *right-click* and choose `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
4. Fill the new window with your preferred shortcut and select `OK`

Now you should be able to use the shortcut to come back to a previous view.

I hope this could help you.